# How to disable XA Transactions for MQ Resource adapters?

Tags: jboss, jms, mq, jca, resource-adapter

How to disable XA Transactions for MQ Resource adapters (e.g. IBM) in JBOSS EAP 6.4?

I want  to use LocalTransaction or NoTransaction mode.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised to see so little information on this. Btw,

> property name="RecoveryEnvironmentBean.periodicRecoveryPeriod"
>   value="0" property
>   name="RecoveryEnvironmentBean.recoveryBackoffPeriod" value="0"

will switch off the XA periodic recovery.
I am still finding a way to completely disable it.

Comment: Where do you set these values in JBOSS EAP 6.3?